# Image of the entire domain of function $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given a function: $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2-1)(x^2+y^2-4) $

I have to find: $f(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$, so I suppose that I have to find the image of that function on the whole domain.

How to do that?

Comment: $f(x, y) = g(x^2 + y^2)$ with $g(t) := (t-1)(t-4)$, that might simplify things ...

Comment: Incidentally, this is the surface of revolution of the curve $z = r^4-5r^2+4$ around the $z$-axis.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

The value of $x^2+y^2$ can be any non-negative real number. So let $r=x^2+y^2$ and you get

$$g(r)=(r-1)(r-4)$$

You should easily be able to find the range of that function for $r\ge 0$. That is the range of your original function.

Comment: So I found the local minimum of $g(r)$ at $r=\frac{5}{2}$ and $g(\frac{5}{2})=-\frac{9}{4}$ Is the image of $f(x,y)$ equal to $[-\frac{9}{4} ; \infty )$ ?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, that is right. The minimum is found wherever $x^2+y^2=\frac 52$, and there is no maximum.